# Strategies and patters on enabling/disabling beta/unfinished code

Tags: java

What are some of the strategies you employ to enable/disable BETA features during run-time.
Or on a similar note, dealing with unfinished code, rather than removing the code, just disabling it or making it dormant.

In the past I've used properties/xml files and/or VM args (-D) to create a global object and use it to check what features to enable/disable, but seems kinda clunky. Has anyone else dealt with a similar problems? What have you done in these cases?

**Note:** I know that best practice would be to have two separate code branches and distribute separate artifacts based on what they need to run, but the "powers that be" think it's easier to dynamically enable/disable features during run-time, rather than maintaining separate branches and integration environments.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue where I work with the same reasoning. We gate it with config files and if the config file isn't present, the feature isn't enabled.

The config file is something like featureGate.config. Each feature is an entry and we have a class that checks against that config for specific feature sets enabled or disabled.